# Need help with .htaccess to hide PHP extension, but with some specific conditions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Here's what I want to achieve:

```
www.mydomain.com/pages/23/page-title-hash-here -> www.mydomain.com/pages.php/23
www.mydomain.com/[otherpages] -> www.mydomain.com/[otherpages].php
www.mydomain.com/[otherpages]/ -> www.mydomain.com/[otherpages].php
```

Essentially, there are some simple pages that are queried by just the filename `(www.mydomain.com/contact or www.mydomain.com/faq)` and then there are pages that I refer to by using the `pages.php/23/fdjsoipfahsd or products.php/54/gf-dsdfs-a-f`  and then I use the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` var to parse through everything after the .php and retrieve the product ID or page ID etc. And there are many variants of these pages..

If I need to hardcode for each .php filename that has trails, I can do that too - we won't be adding any more. However the ones without any trails should still work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't use just:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +MultiViews
```

If I'm understanding it right, it should work.
Try it.

Comment: Oh wow so far it works like a miracle. Genius! I will test a bit further to confirm and then hand out the points!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following.  It ignores requests for files which exists (eg. '/images/image.jpg' would be unaffected), and for ones that don't, it'll attempt to add ".php" to the first 'directory' element, as long as that 'directory' contains only alphanumeric characters.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule  ^/([\w-]*)/?$    /$1.php  [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule  ^/([\w-]*)/(.*)$    /$1.php/$2  [L]
```

- /test/fred/go -> /test.php/fred/go
- /images/image.jpg -> /images/image.jpg (assuming this file exists)
- /script.php/request/thing -> /script.php/request/thing (because the opening 'directory' has a dot in it)
- /test -> /test.php

Comment: WHat if I need to allow for files with dashes (-) and underscores (_) in the file? Such as about-us or contact-us going to about-us.php and contact-us.php?

Comment: I've updated the rules above to allow "-" and "_" to be part of the initial 'directory'.

Comment: Hmm doesn't work... http://picnetbc.sonikastudios.com/about-picnet.php and http://picnetbc.sonikastudios.com/about-picnet are the pages in question.

Comment: Also, can http://picnetbc.sonikastudios.com/about-picnet/3/management-office forward to http://picnetbc.sonikastudios.com/about-picnet.php as well, and I can use the rest of the URI (/3/management-office) to make a query?

Comment: I've improved the rules to correct the initial problem.  When you say to make a query, do you mean something like 'about-picnet.php?p=3&m=management-office' or 'about-picnet.php/3/management-office'?

Comment: about-picnet.php/3/management-office is just fine - I don't need it translated into GET variables at all. I can just explode the REQUEST_URI variable to extract the IDs etc. without a problem. Thanks for this, i'll try this out again

Comment: Hmm still no luck.. http://picnetbc.sonikastudios.com/about-picnet  and http://picnetbc.sonikastudios.com/about-picnet.php - try them out. The first one returns a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which will help you in achieving your requirements:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/(pages|products)\/(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)$ %1.php/%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/([a-z]+)([\/]?)
RewriteRule (.*)$ %1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !(.*\.php)$
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php
RewriteCond $1 !(.*\.php)$
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$1.php/$2 [R=301]
```

These rules rewrite only if file does not end with .php. Then in second case I set a redirect 301 as in php files you are using .php to get the request part. Without R parameter, the script will not find .php and your request string will be empty and will show default page, if I am correct.

Comment: Same thing... http://picnetbc.sonikastudios.com/surveillance-research.php and http://picnetbc.sonikastudios.com/surveillance-research shoudl both work but it does not.

Comment: Have a look at updated answer. This is working on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

1. RewriteRule ^/pages/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /pages.php/$1
2. RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1.php
3. RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ /$1.php

Answer (score 1):

Please reference the following URLs:

- http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php
- http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/02/hide-php-url-rewriting-htaccess.html
- http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php
- http://www.phpgenious.com/2010/04/url-rewriting-with-php-and-iis-7/

Comment: Dude I guess he is searching for answers not links. :)